# Tool recommendation for data transform

Tags: powerbi, dax, azure-data-factory

I have large amounts of raw fault data in Power BI.

```
code    time                    status  
x123    2019-04-22T23:57:00     ok  
x123    2019-04-23T01:00:00     faulty  
x123    2019-04-23T02:00:00     ok  
x123    2019-04-23T23:00:00     faulty  
x123    2019-04-24T01:00:00     ok
```

I need to transform this to show how long an item has been in a faulty state on a given day. So on the 23rd, the item was in a faulty state between 1 and 2a.m and then again between 11pm until past midnight.

```
code    day         % of day faulty  
x123    23/04/2019  8.30%           (2 hours)
```

Can I do this easily in Power BI or should I use another tool such as Azure Data Factory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following Calculated Columns to your table:

`Report Date = Table1[time].[Date]`

```
Fault Duration = 
VAR CurrentTime = Table1[time]
VAR CurrentCode = Table1[code]
VAR PreviousTime = 
    CALCULATE ( 
        MAX ( Table1[time] ),
        FILTER ( 
            Table1,
            Table1[time] < CurrentTime && 
            Table1[code] = CurrentCode
        )
    )
VAR NextTime = 
    CALCULATE ( 
        MIN ( Table1[time] ),
        FILTER ( 
            Table1,
            Table1[time] > CurrentTime && 
            Table1[code] = CurrentCode
        )
    )
VAR FaultyFrom = 
    IF(
        Table1[status] = "faulty",
        Table1[time],
        IF (
            DAY(PreviousTime) = DAY(Table1[time]),
            BLANK(),
            Table1[time].[Date]
        )
    )
VAR FaultyTo = 
    IF ( 
        Table1[status] = "ok",
        Table1[time],
        IF (
            DAY(NextTime) = DAY(Table1[time]),
            NextTime,
            Table1[time].[Date] + 1
        )
    )
RETURN
    IF(
        ISBLANK ( PreviousTime ) || ISBLANK ( NextTime ) || ISBLANK ( FaultyFrom ),
        BLANK(),
        FaultyTo - FaultyFrom
    )
```

Now create measures:

`Faulty Hours = SUM ( Table1[Fault Duration] )`

```
Faulty % Day = 
    IF ( 
        HASONEVALUE ( Table1[Report Date] ),
        DIVIDE ( 
            [Faulty Hours],
            DISTINCTCOUNT ( Table1[code] ),
            BLANK()
        ),
        BLANK()
    )
```

Output:

[image]

See https://pwrbi.com/so_55825688/ for a worked example PBIX file

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks so much

Comment: @Olly I am trying to create calculated column "PreviousTime" from your answer. It works when I put "CurrentTime" and "CurrentCode" on right side of comparison. However, it does not work, when I put Table1[time] and Table1[code] on the right side. It results in all blank values. Could you please explain this behaviour?

Comment: Context. We have row level context when we evaluate the variables. `CALCULATE` forces a context transition (which is what we want, as we want to look at all rows of the table), so the row level context no longer exists. We could use `EARLIER ( Table1[time] )` instead of the variable, but there's a (minor) performance gain from only evaluating the variables once.

Comment: @Olly Thank you for the explanation. I understood now.